# How to have header/footer stay in place while the content is scrolled?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

How to make the Header and Footer stay in place while the content (in the middle of screen is being scrolled)?

I have tried to do it using 'flex' property with no avail thus far.

The example code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { FlatList } from "react-native-web";


export default function App() {
    const items = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= 200; i++) {
        items.push(`Item number ${i}`);
    }

    return (

        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View>
                <Text>HEADER VALUE</Text>
            </View>
            
            <FlatList
                data={items}
                keyExtractor={item => item}
                renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item}</Text>}/>

            <View>
                <Text>FOOTER VALUE</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
});
```

Expo Snack of this code:https://snack.expo.io/NAoplIFmA

The current behavior is that the header is gets scrolled away as if the entire screen was surrounded with the scroll view. But the screen is surrounded with regular view so I would have expected the FlatList to be scrollable while the Header stays in place.

What is the proper way to make the header/footer stay in place while the contents of FlatList become scrollable?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the position: "fixed"

Here you go, this should solve it.. Make changes according to your needs.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { FlatList } from "react-native-web";


export default function App() {
    const items = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= 200; i++) {
        items.push(`Item number ${i}`);
    }

    return (

        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style = {styles.header}>
                <Text style = {{textAlign:'center'}}>HEADER VALUE</Text>
            </View>
            
            <FlatList
                data={items}
                keyExtractor={item => item}
                renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item}</Text>}/>

            <View style = {styles.footer}>
                <Text>FOOTER VALUE</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header:
  {
    position:"fixed",
    top:0,
    left:0,
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent:'center',
    width:'100%',
    backgroundColor:'blue',
    height:'50px'

  },
  footer:
  {
    position:"fixed",
    bottom:0,
    left:0,
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent:'center',
    width:'100%',
    backgroundColor:'blue',
    height:'50px'

  },
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        marginTop:'50px'
    },
});
```